# MPI datatype alignment

Tags: c, mpi

I'm working on a sample coding but just couldn't get send and receive the same value.

the datatype i create is

```
typedef struct customData{
    double iv;
    double dv[5];
    char cv[10];
} customData;
```

I create datatype here

```
MPI_Datatype type;
MPI_Datatype ctype[3] = {MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_CHAR};
int blocklen[3] = {1, 5, 10};
MPI_Aint disp[3] = { 0, sizeof(double), sizeof(double)*6 };

MPI_Type_create_struct(1, blocklen, disp, ctype, &type);
MPI_Type_commit(&type);
```

send and receive

```
if(rank == 0){
    customData data = {5, 
            {1,2,3,4,5}, 
            {'h','d','h','a','q','w','e','s','l','z'}};
    printf("%f %.2f %c\n", data.iv, data.dv[0], data.cv[0]);

    MPI_Send(&data, 1, type, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);     
} else {
    customData recv;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Recv(&recv, 1, type, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    printf("%f %.2f %c\n", recv.iv, recv.dv[0], recv.cv[0]);
}
```

The output is
 
5.000000 1.00 h
5.000000 0.00 �

Comment: Generally speaking, you should use `offsetof()` to populate the displacements array (since the compiler might add some padding here and there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the number of element in the structure in your MPI_Type_create_struct, 3 instead of 1.

```
MPI_Type_create_struct(3, blocklen, disp, ctype, &type);
```

I tested it and I got:

```
5.000000 1.00 h
5.000000 1.00 h
```

Some info here:

[Trouble Understanding MPI_Type_create_struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33618937/trouble-understanding-mpi-type-create-struct)

[struct serialization in C and transfer over MPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864510/struct-serialization-in-c-and-transfer-over-mpi)

Comment: so the "count" is not the number of ctype but the number of entries?

Comment: you have 3 variables in ctype corresponding to the 3 variables of your structure. If your structure was made of n variables, you would use count=n. I hope it helps!